# Wamp Server 3 not listing localhost dir after dir root change

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

Ok, brand new Windows 10 Installation without IIS or Skype (Port 80 is open).

Installed WAMP 3 64bit version Worked like a charm!

Changed the `httpd.conf` file so I could redirect the `www` folder to `D:/www/`

Deleted the Old www folder and copied all my projects to the new folder at `D:/www/`(each project within it's own folder) leaving www root folder without a index.php or any other type of index file

Ok now comes the problem... Restarted all services, and when typing `localhost` or `http://localhost/`, on any browser, it gives me 404 Not Found...

If I try to access `localhost/site1/` (for example) everything works fine so WAMP is working...

But...

On Linux it used to list all folders so I could click on them like a dir list a sort of navigation structure...

Why Wamp is not doing the same?

Maybe something to do with `.htaccess`? And if So, how to resolve it?

Thanks in Advance

JohnnyBR

Comment: Jow, nice flag, try using another port, like 8080 for a while (may be the system is "waiting" for a future IIS installation?). 2) have a look at your **hosts** file, it may be prohibiting you some things, not shure. 3) Your WAMP doesn't have a control panel or something like this?. 4) What about 127.0.0.1? 5) Are you trying something like ASP.NET or...? If so, try using a plain HTML at the begining, just for test. Another things: 6) ensure that WAMP is ON and running (see running activities by ctl+alt+del). 7) If you find the log files of WAMP, some things may arise, f. ex. an 403 or 404 err.

Comment: @statosdotcom Its obviously not a port problem as he says `localhost/site1` works

Comment: Look at this post on the [wampserver forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) Specifically the second post about creating Apache Virtual Hosts, one for each of your projects. You could also read [The need for virtual hosts](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) as well. Put WAMPServer back the way it was after the initial Install and put your Virtual Hosts anywhere you want on any mapped drive. Oh and this is not a WAMPServer thing, you probably shoudl have done this on Linux Apache as well.

Comment: RiggsFolly, you're right, thanks. I see now that many of the items I listed on my first comment was obtuse because of my first equivocate view. All the matter of João, I think, is about "directory listing". João: try to figure out if something like a "redirecting" is occurring on the root, this maybe raising the 404 you find. Empty the root directory, 404 happens too? If so, to where address bar indicate? There is a chance httpd.conf has to allow directory listing?

Comment: Riggs is probably right I maybe had done this before in Linux but didn't remember well... I do remember something about Allow Directory listing too StatOsDOTCOM... Thank you both I'll read all guides now and after that I'll post here the outcomes!!! btw call me Johnny is Easier :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to this problem but it works! It's a bypass!

After reading all guides I could found, creating `.htaccess` files, changing conf files and everything, I couldn't fix this problem (I didn't wanted to try understanding virtual hosts... If I got that right I'd have to make a virtual host for each site... not the thing I want)

So I made a quick fix and here it is:

I created a `index.php` with this code

```
<?php
$d = dir(".");
echo "Path: " . $d->path . "\n";
echo "<ul>";
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
   echo "<li><a href='{$entry}'>{$entry}</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
$d->close();
?>
```

And that's it folks! Same effect! If apache is not helping nor wamp server PHP will do it!

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly and statosdotcom for their help.... I just don't have the time to figure it out and this works likewise...